# Putting zero hours under a process for a PMI application

Tags: pmp

As you all know, project descriptions are limited to 550 characters in the PMI application. In two projects in my list, I decided to highlight tasks I did in the planning and the monitoring processes and did not put anything under the executing process. This is in order to mention things I never did previously and ran out of characters to explain what I did in the execution phase. Also, in previous projects, I have already demonstrated experience in executing a project.

However, while allotting hours to each phase, I am doubtful if I should put down zero hours in execution since I did do some tasks in the execution phase of the project though. I was thinking that I might put down a token 10 hours just not to leave it at zero. Kindly advice.

Comment: The only advice anyone here should give you on this question is: record your hours as accurately as you can.  Token does not equal accurate.

Comment: You don't need to have experience in all processes for EVERY project. So it would be unnecessary to put in any "token hours".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a PMI application you should focus on what you did in project managment, not what you didn't. It is not relevant to mention what you did not do. You should have PM experience in all project process groups. My suggestion would be to summarize a little bit other processes and add a short description in the execution phase. Then add the 10 hours of course. It's better than leaving at zero.